# Android: File downloaded from website differs from original

Tags: android, file, download

My original intention was download a new version of my android application (myApp.apk) from my website and update the running application on device...
There was a problem, because I realized the file downloaded is different of the file in website, I do a binary comparison and there a lot of areas differents. Someone could give a clue?

This is the code I used to download the file:

```
    URLConnection ucon = null;

    try 
    {
       URL url = new URL("http://www.mySite.com/folder/myApp.apk");
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
       urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
       urlConnection.connect();
       File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"FileDownloaded11.apk");
       FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
       InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
       int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
       int downloadedSize = 0;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
       int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer
       while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
       {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;

        }
        fileOutput.close();
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I would not use `URLConnection.getContentLength()` as the value will be `-1` if the length is not known. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29. Also, ensure your `FileOutputStream` is closed properly by placing it in a `finally` block. Also, check the `bufferLength` is `> -1`, not `> 0`.

Comment: hi @PaulGrime, thanks for your answer, you are right about URLConnection.getContentLength, running in emulator the  file is downloaded (getContentLength is > -1), but in device not...Also, my primary question still persists, why (in emulator) the files differs, the downloaded and original?

Comment: Is there a pattern to the differences? E.g. the file is being interpreted as text somewhere along the way, and things that look like newlines are being converted? Or perhaps anything that looks like accented characters is being converted between ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8, that kind of thing?